# Populating two inter-related columns in a R data.table

Tags: r, vector, data.table

I have this sample data table:

```
df <- data.table(indexer = c(0:12), x1 =
                   c(0,1000,1500,1000,1000,2000,
                     1000,1000,0,351.2,1000,1000,1851.2)
                                  )
```

Now I need to create two additional columns `x2` and `x3` in this data frame such as `x2[i] = x1[i] - x3[i]` and `x3[i] = x2[i-1]` with `x3[1]=0`.

How can I do this without using a loop in an efficient way?

**EDIT1:** expected results are

```
x2 = c(0.0,1000.0,500.0,500.0,500.0,1500.0,-500.0,1500.0,-1500.0,1851.2,-851.2,1851.2‌​,0.0)
```

and

```
x3 = c(0.0,0.0,1000.0,500.0,500.0,500.0,1500.0,-500.0,1500.0,-1500.0,1851.2,-851.2,18‌​51.2)
```

**EDIT2:** First time here posting questions. Hence all these confusions. Forget the example guys, the formulas are:

`x3[i] = c - x2[i-1]*(1+r/12); x2[i] = x1[i] - x3[i]; x3[1] = 0;` # c is some constant.

Comment: Dou you mean `x3[1]=0` or `x3[13] = 0`, because `[i-1]` creates a missing value on the 13. line of `x3`

Comment: @DibuJohn, you most likely have a typo in definitions of the columns `x2` and `x3`, because they depend on each other

Comment: @DibuJohn Could you show the expected result?  From the description, it seems `df[, c('x3', 'x2') := {tmp=c(0,x1[-.N]); x1-tmp}]`, but the two columns x3 and x2 are identical.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick replies!  @RStudent x3[1]=0; x3[13]=x2[12].  So how can 13the line of x3 be a missing value?

Comment: @MaratTalipov Yes they are dependent on each other, hence the problem!

Comment: @akrun expected results are x2 = c(0.0,1000.0,500.0,500.0,500.0,1500.0,-500.0,1500.0,-1500.0,1851.2,-851.2,1851.2,0.0) and x3 = c(0.0,0.0,1000.0,500.0,500.0,500.0,1500.0,-500.0,1500.0,-1500.0,1851.2,-851.2,1851.2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `x2` and `x3` depend on each other. Thus, one needs to express `x2` in terms of `x1`:

[image]

Once we have the formula, programming is easy:

```
df$x2 <- (-1)^(df$indexer) * cumsum(df$x1*(-1)^(df$indexer))
```

And `x3` can be obtained from `x2`:

```
df$x3 <- c(0,df$x2[-nrow(df)])
```

[EDIT2] I guess that solution for the  modified question, if it exists at all, should be sought along the same lines. I don't think it should be considered as a programming-related problem, because the code is quite straightforward once the mathematical formula is known.

Comment: Aah I messed it up again! Really sorry guys; here's the actual formulas: x3[i] = c - x2[i-1]*(1+r/12); x2[i] = x1[i] - x3[i]; x3[1] = 0; c is some constant.

Comment: There's no 0-index in R.